# Sitecore 7.5 to other MVC Solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore7.5

I am trying to add sitecore to an existing solution where we already have an MVC Application.Now after adding Sitecore,I will make sitecore as start up project and add the reference of existing MVC Application as a reference to Sitecore MVC Application.

Since the existing application was using 4.5.1 and MVC 5.2.3,I am also using the same for my sitecore application.But the existing MVC application is using below:
1. System.Web.Http (Version:5.2.3.0)
2. System.Web.Http.WebHost (Version:5.2.3.0)
3. System.Net.Http.Formatting (Version:5.2.3.0)

So can I use the same for Sitecore?.If yes then I will have to Modify Web Config

From:

```
<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="false" targetFramework="4.5.1">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Http, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

To:

```
<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="false" targetFramework="4.5.1">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Is this change fine?.Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verified with sitecore support and they confirmed that all the above changes are fine.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding Sitecore to your solution you should probably look at it the other way around I.e getting your Mvc application to work in Sitecore.

You shouldn't really change the assembly versions Sitecore is using and you should try to get your Mvc application to work with Sitecore. You can't 100% guarantee that Sitecore will work using higher or lower versions of assemblies that it needs. Whereas with your Mvc solution (I'm assuming you have the source code) you can always try to modify this to work with Sitecore.

Comment: :Thanks for the reply.On the similar lines ,I have one more question.The existing mVC Application is making use of some of the NUget Packages like Microsoft.Owin(Version - 3.0.1) and Newtonsoft.Json(Version - 6.0.8 ),but when I create a visual studio solution for sitecore with MVC template by default it adds Microsoft.Owin (3.0.0 )and Newtonsoft.Json (6.0.4 ).

So there is a version mismatch.For this I am thinking of upgrading all these packages (and many more) in sitecore project to match my existing mvc application.Is this fine?